# Finding hypersurface equations in order to find unit normals

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I've been a bit confused while trying to work with hypersurfaces in special relativity. I understand that if we are working in Minkowski space and we have a surface where $t=\text{const.}$, the hypersurface equation would be $f(t) = t - \text{const.} = 0$. I can then use the gradient to find that the normal is given by $n^a = (1,0,0,0)$. This part is pretty clear to me. However, I'm having difficulty jumping to the next step, which is considering a surface such as a 2-sphere, where $t=\text{const.}$ and $r=\text{const.}$. How can I find the equation of the hypersurface for this situation? In other words, I'm having difficulty finding the right hypersurface equation.

I thought it would perhaps be something of the form $f(t,r) = t + r -(\text{const.}_1 +\text{const.}_2) = 0$, where the constants aren't necessarily the same, but I think that's incorrect. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to find this equation so that I can determine the unit normal to this hypersurface (and then characterize it as spacelike, timelike, or null).

Comment: It is not  a hypersurface and one equation is not enough.

Comment: @MBN I imagine you are referring to my function $f(t)$, and not the 2-sphere. I was trying to show my work so that one could perhaps point out what I'm doing incorrectly. I'm looking for the hypersurface equation to the 2-sphere so I can find the unit normal.

Comment: Be careful that not every submanifold is globally of the form $F=0$, even if the codimension is greater than $1$ and $F$ is vector-valued.

Comment: A two dimensional surface in a four dimensional manifold is not a hypersurface. The term hypersurface usually refers to a codimansion one submanifold. In your case it is codimansion two. One equation will not be enough. You will need two. And you have written them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$, a submanifold $S$ of dimension $n-p$ is defined by a set of $p$ functions $f^a(x)$, where $a$ runs from $1$ to $p$, as the set of points $x$ where the $f^a$ are equal to some constant $f^a_*$. If a function is constant along a submanifold, that means $V^\mu \nabla_\mu f^a = 0$, where $V^\mu$ are all the vectors tangent to the submanifold and $\nabla_\mu$ is the covariant derivative.
Hence, the normal to the submanifold is given by a linear combination of all of the $\nabla_\mu f^a$, that is $\xi_\mu = h_a \nabla_\mu f^a$, where $h_a$ is any function of the $x$. As $\xi_\mu$ is a dual vector, to get a vector you have to raise the index via the metric tensor $g_{\mu \nu}$, that is $\xi^\mu = g^{\mu \nu} \xi_\nu$.
In the question you define a submanifold of dimension $2$ in Minkowski, as $t = constant$ and $r = constant$, where radial coordinates $(t, r, \theta, \phi)$ are used. The normals are $\partial_t = (1, 0, 0, 0)$ and $\partial_r = (0, 1, 0, 0)$. As they are defined as dual vectors, to get the vectors you have to raise the indices via the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu \nu} = diag(-1, 1, r^2, r^2 \sin^2 \theta)$, that is $(\partial^t)^\mu = \eta^{\mu \nu} (\partial_t)_\nu = (-1, 0, 0, 0)$ and $(\partial^r)^\mu = \eta^{\mu \nu} (\partial_r)_\nu = (0, 1, 0, 0)$. Any linear combination of $\partial^t$ and $\partial^r$ is a normal vector to the submanifold. To have a unit normal vector you have to constrain the coefficients.
Note: 1) When applied to a scalar the covariant derivative reduces to the partial derivative. 2) When raising the indices you use the inverse metric tensor.